# Safari transforms SVG wrong

Tags: css, svg, safari, webkit

I made a little CSS animation with a simple svg to transition my hamburger menu to a cross. It works as expected on Chrome and Firefox, but the translation is off in Safari. The animation plays, and even resets correctly so it has nothing to do with prefixes (I tried). The translate of the two lines making the cross is just wrong.
I'm guessing it has something to do with how safari handles the transform when scaling is also applied. Does anyone know if there is a work around / or what I'm doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eggplantPrince/04svyoLf/)

[image: Safari vs Firefox vs Chrome]
Safari / Firefox / Chrome

```
@keyframes showCross {
  0% {
   transform: scale(1) rotate(0);
  }

 40% {
   transform: scale(0.3) rotate(280deg);

 }

 100% {
   transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes showCross_P1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-42%, -10%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing the following:

First I removed the groups surrounding the paths.
Then I gave all the paths the following values:

```
transform-origin:center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
```

Next I edited the animation keyframes to look as follows:

```
0% {
   transform:  translate(0rem,0rem) rotate(0);
}
100% {
   transform: translate(-10rem,-38rem) rotate(-45deg) ;
}
```

Safari has problems with percents and also if you put the rotation before the translate it has inconsistency with other browsers, use rem instead!